# How did they apply the Tower property $E[X] = E[E[X\mid Y]]$

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Iam trying to understand a proof in my book but there is one detail that i don't get, here it is:

Let $C_1,C_2,...C_{j+k}$ be random varibles:

$E[C_{j+k} \mid C_1,...C_{j} ] = E\Big[ E[C_{j+k} \mid C_1,...C_{j+k-1}] \quad \mid C_1,...,C_j \Big] $

I know they are using $E[X] = E[E[X\mid Y]]$ somehow but i can't figure out how

Comment: Perhaps some coloring would help? $$E[C_{j+k}| \color{green}{C_1,\ldots, C_j}] = E\left[ E [ C_{j+k} | \color{green}{C_1,\ldots, C_j},\color{red}{C_{j+1}, \ldots, C_{j+k-1}}] | \color{green}{C_1,\ldots, C_j}\right]$$ Perhaps the confusion lies in the fact that the first expacted values already contains a condition? $$E[A|C] = E\left[ E[A|B, C] | C\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the image below will clarify further why:

$$E[A|\color{blue}{B}] = E\left[\;E[A|C,\color{blue}{B}]\;|\color{blue}{B}\right]$$

#### Warning: the following is not a formal explanation, more a intuitivly feel to the matter:

Let $A$ be represented by the square below. (I'm using Bernouilli variables for simplicity)
You know already:
$$E[A] = E\left[ \;E[A|B] \;\right]$$
Or in more *friendly* words: "Averaging over $A$ is like taking the average of the averages of 
the subsets $A|B=1$ and $A|B=0$."

Nu consider an extra random variable $C$.

Consider $E[A|B]$ which **is dependant** of the value of $B$ since $E[A|B=0]$ and $E[A|B=1]$ could 
return different answers. (although in the picture the *areas* are similar)

For instance $E[A|B=1]$ can be written down (using the 'tower rule') as $E\left[ \; E[A|C,B=1]\;\right]$
Or once again "Averaging over $A|B=1$ is like taking the average of averages on the subparts $A|C=0,B=1$ and $A|C=1,B=1$."

Similar $E[A|B=0] = E\left[ \; E[A|C,B=0]\;\right]$

*But* since the original question was $E[A|B]$ you don't know which iterated expected value you should use.
That's why you need extra condition on $B$.
$$E[A|\color{blue}{B}] = E\left[\;E[A|C,\color{blue}{B}]\;|\color{blue}{B}\right]$$

[image: Conditional]

Comment: So you mean that $E[A\mid B=1] = E[E[A\mid B=1]\mid C=c ]= E[ E[A\mid B=1,C=c]] +...$ for all values of $C$, but i really only care about that last equality , because it is whats confusing me. @dietervdf

Comment: No, you got the order wrong: $$E[A|B=1] = E[\;\color{green}{E[A|C=C,B=1]}\; | B=1]$$ You take the *average* of each outcome $C=c$ and $B=1$ which is $\color{green}{E[A|C=C,B=1]}$. Then you take the *average* of this but only knowing the outcome $B=1$. (which makes the sample space *smaller*). The identity you propose doesn't make any sense. Do you mean $A|(B|C)$ or $(A|B)|C$? I guess there might be distrubtions where this identity would hold, but it's **not** a rule.

Comment: It is still confusing me because Iam always comparing to the case where we do not have the condition $E[A]=E [E[A\mid B]]$ in this case you go trough all values of $B$ to obtain $E[A]$, in the case $E[A\mid B]$ you should then go trough all values of $C$ as $E[E[A\mid B,C] \mid C]] $ to obtain $E[A \mid B]$ , i might have understood this property completely.@dietervdf